# Add commas to list of JSON object

Tags: javascript, php, python, json

I have text file who contains a list of objects.

```
{ a:"1", b:"2", c: "3"}{ a:"1", b:"2", c: "3"}{ a:"1", b:"2", c: "3"}
```

I want to make it valid Json file. For instanse:

```
[{ a:"1", b:"2", c: "3"},{ a:"1", b:"2", c: "3"},{ a:"1", b:"2", c: "3"}]
```

The file is very big - 600mb. I need to do this with languages who can change files. I tried to find solution but I couldn't.

Comment: What is your array? please show your array.

Comment: Can these objects have nested objects inside them?

Comment: Add `[`, `]` and replace `}{` with `},{`?

Comment: this will be a nightmare if we need to write a parser yourself it will help if the next element have a new line between them if not you need to detect the start of the curly bracket and end of the curly bracket

Comment: in python: read file and replace }{ with },{ => `re.sub(r'}{', '},{', file_text)`

Answer (score 3):

KISS: replace `}{` with `},{` and wrap in `[]`

Comment: This is not an answer. OP is asking for a method to do that but since file is very large it cannot be done using simple file editor.

Comment: How is it not an answer? Do it programatically, efficiently reading the file with any of the listed languages and using a straightforward standard library function, a process that doesn't need much explanation.

Comment: Well that's what this question is about, **the method**. Don't you think OP already knows that `}{` should be replaced by `},{`. So this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I am answering the exact question OP stated - how to make a text file with the given syntax a valid JSON file, and you are the one assuming it to be something else.

Answer (score 3):

A sloppy but simple solution in Python:

```
import json
tmp = '{ "a":"1", "b":"2", "c": "3"}{ "a":"1", "b":"2", "c": "3"}{ "a":"1", "b":"2", "c": "3"}' # test string
tmp = tmp.replace('}{', '},{') # replace '}{' with '},{'
tmp = '[' + tmp + ']' # add brackets around it
json_string = json.loads(tmp) # confirm that it's valid json
print(json_string) # print the json_string
```

will print

```
[{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}, {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}, {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hello I saw this help can serve as a contribution. inside the first def comma_json add; and the structure_json adds [] to everything**

def comma_json():

```
with open("file1.json", "r+") as f:
    old = f.read()
    f.seek(0)  # rewind
    f.write(old.replace('}{', '},{'))
    f.close

def structure_json():
  with open("file1.json", "r+") as f:
    old = f.read()
   with open("file2.json", "w") as r:
    tmps = '[' + str(old) + ']'
    json_string = json.loads(tmps)

    json.dump(json_string, r, indent=2)
    f.close
```

Answer (score 0):

not a best solution but it works follow below steps

1. if the input is in object format then convert into string json.stringify()
2. replace "}{" with "},{" and append add open and close brackets at the start and end of the string
3. now convert string to object.

Comment: I cannot do that. I have nested objects:
{"username":"","last_name":" ","links":[],"twitter":"","created_on":"","has_default_image":"","images":{"50":"images","115":"images","138":"images"},"id":"","occupation":"","city":"","first_name":"","display_name":"","state":"","location":"","sections":[],"website":"","company":"","stats":{"team_members":0,"views":0,"appreciations":0,"comments":0,"followers":0,"following":0},"url":"","country":"","social_links":[],"fields":[]}

Comment: but you didn't mentioned that in your requirement.

Comment: if you need a proper solution take sometime update your question with required information. I can see in your comments nested objects already are comma separated but its not a valid json there are some special characters.

Answer (score -1):

u can use like this

```
  [
    { "a":"1", 
      "b":"2", 
      "c": "3"
    },
    { "a":"1", 
      "b":"2", 
      "c": "3"
    },
    { "a":"1", 
      "b":"2", 
      "c": "3"
    }
 ]
```

Comment: this does not answer the question at all